# Detecting Valid Input on amp-form

Tags: amp-html

Is there an event that enables you to detect when an input has been successfully updated?

The closest I have managed to get is below but this only detects that the value has changed and does not check whether it is a valid input. I'm using amp-bind to enable a navigation button to guide the user through the form.

The objective is to make sure that the user cannot proceed until there is a valid entry in each input.

```html
<input
type="text"
id="postcode"
name="postcode"
placeholder="Postcode"
pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9Rr][0-9A-Za-z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}"
on="change:AMP.setState({mainApplication: {postcode: event.value}})"
class="user-invalid valueMissing"
aria-invalid="true"
required>

<button
id="nextSection-2"
type="button"
class="button large alert"
on="tap:apply-section-2.show,apply-section-1.hide" [disabled]="!mainApplication.ownerStatus || !mainApplication.postcode || !mainApplication.houseNumber"
disabled>
Next
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I found is [this issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/10242), you may want to explain your case there to check if it's the same issue.